# Error Integrating TFS 2017 U3 with SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services

Tags: tfs

When I try to integrate TFS 2017 U3 with SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services, from TFS Administration Console, an error appear. Please see screenshot.

In the event viewer of TFS server, I see registered this error:

> DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer servername using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID
>   1080 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018\Tools\TfsMgmt.exe).

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP194.jpg)

I have had checked the following:

- Windows Firewall is not blocking port 80
- Reporting service is started
- User Account has required permissions
- WMI is running on the report Server
- TFS databases are in the same server than reporting services and the TFS service is running without any problem.

Please, any idea how to revolve this error will be very appreciated

Comment: Are you on TFS 2018, or TFS 2017? The path in your log message indicates it's 2018.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong when placing the error text messaage. I had performed a test from TFS 2018 that's the reason why I wrote with that description eror, but the productive environment is with TFS 2017 U3 and the error message is the same thing; the difference is the path where TfsMgmt.exe is located.

Thanks for your attention.

Audberto